# Javascript Date comparison coming from server and new Date()

Tags: javascript

I have a date coming from database which is 2022-10-31 11:33:07.861Z, and in my js file I have this date is saved in a variable :

```
function test() {
let now = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'Europe/London'}); // I need now to be Europe/london time 
let dateFromDb = db_date; // 2022-10-31 11:33:07.861Z
// I have a function which takes ^ above date and returns this : Mon Oct 31 2022 11:33:07 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)

let formatedDate= this.toDate(dateFomDb); // returns : Mon Oct 31 2022 11:33:07 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
}
```

When I console.log(now, typeOf now) I get this:  02/11/2022, 23:24:52 string
and console for formatedDate returns this  :  Mon Oct 31 2022 11:33:07 GMT+0000 Object

I need to compare both dates :

```
return newDate <= now; // expect it to true or false;
```

Can anyone please suggest me how can I do this ?

I tried to cast both dates toLocalString but its string from I need object.

Comment: Dates in JS have no time zone. Only the output does

Comment: let result = +new Date(dateFromDb) <= Date.now(); would work as it compares the numerical UTC values.  The leading plus sign is just shorthand for Date.valueOf()